# Constant average temperature in the solution of the heat equation with isolated ends

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Given the heat equation $u_t=\alpha^2u_{xx}$, an initial distribution $f(x)=u(t_0,x)$, and the [solution using Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series) of  $u(t,x)$

$$u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}D_n\sin\left({n\pi x\over L}\right)\exp\left(-{n^2\pi^2\alpha t\over L}\right) $$

I understand that the average temperature should be constant if I'm correct, so

$$\bar T=\left({1\over L}\right)\int_0^L u(t,x)\ dx=C $$

Taking ${d\over dt}\bar T$ and matching to  $0$ give the condition...

$${d\bar T\over dt}=\int_0^L \partial_t\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}D_n\sin\left({n\pi x\over L}\right)\exp\left(-{n^2\pi^2\alpha t\over L}\right) \right)\ dx$$

$$=\int_0^L \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-{n^2\pi^2\alpha t\over L}\right)D_n\sin\left({n\pi x\over L}\right)\exp\left(-{n^2\pi^2\alpha t\over L}\right) \right)\ dx $$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-n\pi\alpha t\right)D_n\left(1-\cos\left({n\pi x\over L}\right)\right)\exp\left(-{n^2\pi^2\alpha t\over L}\right)=0$$

Now my question is how can be prove the last equality, or if the conservation of average temperature is false, what is the quantity constant in time.

Comment: I mean, the temperature decays to zero everywhere over time, so the (spatial) average temperature *can't* be conserved.

Comment: Your integration with respect to x is obviously incorrect because you forgot to substitute the value of x at the upper integration limit.

Answer (score 2):

This, in general, depends on the boundary conditions. It's a bit unclear what you mean by "isolated" ends. Insulated ends (ie, no flux, a perfect insulator) would correspond to $u_x(0)=0=u_x(L)$. In this case (see, for example, this [link](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s12/m3357/lectures/lecture_2_28_short.pdf) for details), you would find:

$u(t,x)=a_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)\exp\left( -\frac{n^2 \pi^2 \alpha^2 t}{L^2} \right)$,

where $a_0=\frac{1}{L}\int_0^L f(x)dx$ and $a_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x) \cos\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)dx, n \geq 1$ are the usual cosine Fourier expansion coefficients. In this case, it is easy to see that by integrating $u(t,x)$, the average temperature is constant and equal to $a_0$. The long term behavior is that the temperature everywhere tends to $a_0$.

However, what you have written, and the link you provided, seems to correspond to Dirichlet boundary conditions with $u(0)=0=u(L)$. This physically corresponds to ends that are in contact with a reservoir that maintains a constant temperature at the boundaries of your system. You can see from the solution you have written (with typos corrected):

$u(t,x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  D_n \sin\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \exp\left( -\frac{n^2 \pi^2 \alpha^2 t}{L^2} \right)$,

that the temperature will decay to 0 as $t \to \infty$. So in this case, the average temperature is not conserved, unless the initial temperature profile is $f(x)=0$.